# Send emails with data from spreadsheet files

Tags: python, python-2.x

I wrote a tool to send emails with data saved in excel spreadsheets (.xlsx).
It uses the openpyxl module to interact with the spreadsheets and *smtplib* to send the mails.
It is only tested with (and should only run for) xlsx files generated by google spreadsheets.
It should work with everything openpyxl is supporting, but it doesn't really matter for now.

The tool shall be used to send emails for an [secret santa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Santa) event (i suggested using a website but the organizer want to use mails).
So my main concern is loosing data or sending this private data to the wrong recipient.
Also there is a send limit implemented as the mails accounts that are going to be used are accounts from free hoster (gmail in this case) with a limit of maximum sends per day.
If there would be an error in that part of the code that would be critical, too, as it could lead to a (temporary) banned account.

The complete code follows, but the project [here](https://github.com/SleepProgger/sheetmail) is also containing an README.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.exceptions import CellCoordinatesException, InvalidFileException

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 

import json
import logging
import argparse
import socket
from exceptions import ValueError
from time import sleep, time as now
from math import ceil
import os

log_debug, log_info, log_warn, log_error = logging.debug, logging.info, logging.warn, logging.error

def excel_data_iterator(workbook, sheet_index=0, selected_rows=tuple([0, 5]), row_offset=1):
    workbook.active = sheet_index
    sheet = workbook.active
    for row_number, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows()):
        if row_number < row_offset: continue
        yield (row_number,) + tuple([row[i].value for i in selected_rows])


class Mail_sender():
    def __init__(self, server_config, quota_persist=None, nosend=False):
        self.host = server_config['host']
        self.port = server_config['port']
        self.username = server_config['username']
        self.password = server_config['password']
        self.sender = server_config['sender_addr']
        self.use_ssl = server_config['user_ssl']
        self.config = server_config
        self.nosend = nosend

        self.connected = False
        self.quota_persist = quota_persist
        self.next_send = 0
        self._update_quotas(mail_send=False)

    def _update_quotas(self, mail_send=True):
        curtime = now()
        if curtime >= self.config['timeframe_end']:
            self.config['timeframe_end'] = now() + self.config['timeframe']
            self.config['remaining_requests'] = self.config['allowed_requests']
            self.next_send = now() + self.config['timeframe']
            log_debug('New timeframe for %s@%s:%i. %i Requests till %s' % (self.username, self.host, self.port, self.config['remaining_requests'], self.config['timeframe_end']))
        # TODO: check if send was allowed ?
        if mail_send:
            self.config['remaining_requests'] -= 1            
        if self.config['update_config']:
            self.quota_persist()
        if self.config['use_fixed_delay']:
            if mail_send:
                self.next_send = curtime + ceil(self.config['timeframe'] / self.config['allowed_requests'])
            else:
                self.next_send = curtime
        else:    
            if self.config['remaining_requests'] > 0:
                mail_delay = ceil( (self.config['timeframe_end'] - curtime) / self.config['remaining_requests'] )
                log_debug('Can send 1 mail every %i second for %s@%s:%i. %i requests remaining in frame.' % (mail_delay, self.username, self.host, self.port, self.config['remaining_requests']))
                self.next_send = curtime + (mail_delay if mail_send else 0)
            else:
                self.next_send = self.config['timeframe_end']


    def connect_to_server(self):
        log_debug("Connecting to server %s@%s:%i." % (self.username, self.host, self.port))
        if self.use_ssl:
            self.server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.host, self.port)
            self.server.ehlo() # optional, called by login()
        else:
            self.server = smtplib.SMTP(self.host, self.port)
            self.server.ehlo()
            self.server.starttls()
        self.server.login(self.username, self.password)  
        log_info('Logged in to %s:%i as %s' % (self.host, self.port, self.username))
        self.connected = True

    # TODO: unused atm. remove ?
    def can_send(self):
        return now() >= self.next_send

    def _send_mail(self, mail_to, mail_subject, mail_body):
        if not self.connected:
            self.connect_to_server()
        if isinstance(mail_to, (str, unicode)):
            mail_to = [mail_to]

        msg = MIMEText(mail_body)
        msg['Subject'] = mail_subject
        msg['From'] = self.sender
        msg['To'] = ",".join(mail_to)

        if not self.nosend:
            self.server.sendmail(self.sender, mail_to, msg.as_string())
        log_info('Send mail to %s over %s@%s:%i' % (mail_to, self.username, self.host, self.port))
        self._update_quotas(mail_send=True)

    def send_mail(self, mail_to, mail_subject, mail_body, retries=3, sleep_time=5):
        """
        Tries to send the mail trying to resolve some errors (up to `retries` times).
        If this function returns false, the connection is bugged and should be closed.
        May throw Exceptions:
        - smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused   Wrong recipient. Valid recipients might work.
        """
        for i in xrange(retries):
            try:
                self._send_mail(mail_to, mail_subject, mail_body)
                log_info('Successful send mail from %s to %s (Subject: %s) at %i try.' % (self.sender, mail_to, mail_subject, i+1))
                return True
            except smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused as e:
                # Avoid this being catched by the SMPTException catcher further down
                raise e  
            except smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused as e:
                log_error('The server refused the sender (%s) %s@%s:%i' % (self.sender, self.username, self.host, self.port))
                return False   
            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError as e:
                log_error('SMTP authentication problem for connection %s@%s:%i' % (self.username, self.host, self.port))
                return False   
            except smtplib.SMTPHeloError as e:
                log_error('The server didn\'t reply properly to the HELO greeting.')
                return False
            except smtplib.SMTPDataError as e:
                log_warn('The server replied with an unexpected error code.')
                if i < retries:
                    log_info('Trying to reconnect to %s@%s:%i ...' % (self.username, self.host, self.port))
                    self.close()
                    sleep(sleep_time)
                    self.connected = False
            except socket.error as e:
                log_warn('Socket error: %s .' % e)
                if i < retries:
                    log_info('Trying to reconnect to %s@%s:%i ...' % (self.username, self.host, self.port))
                    self.close()
                    sleep(sleep_time)
                    self.connected = False
            except smtplib.SMTPConnectError as e:
                log_warn('Connection error for %s@%s:%i.' % (self.username, self.host, self.port))
                if i < retries:
                    log_info('Trying to reconnect to %s@%s:%i ...' % (self.username, self.host, self.port))
                    self.close()
                    sleep(sleep_time)
                    self.connected = False
            except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
                log_error('Smtplib error: %s .' % e)
                return False
        log_error('To many retries sending to %s:%i via %s. Giving up.' % (self.host, self.port, self.username))
        return False

    def close(self):
        try: # DealWithIt.mov
            self.server.quit()
        except: pass
        self.connected = False



class Excel_Mail_Sender():
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config;
        self.server_config = None
        self.server_connections = None
        self.wb = None
        self.sheet = None

    def init(self):
        try:
            log_debug("Open", self.config['excel_file'])
            self.wb = load_workbook(self.config['excel_file'], data_only=True, keep_vba=True)
        except CellCoordinatesException, InvalidFileException:
            log_error('Failed to load spreadsheet file "%s"' % self.config['excel_file'])
            return False

        if self.config['cleancomments']:
            log_info("Clean comments from spreadsheet to avoid comment bug.")
            for i in xrange(len(self.wb.get_sheet_names())):
                self.wb.active = i
                for row in self.wb.active.rows:
                    for cell in row: cell.comment = None

        self.wb.active = self.config['sheetindex']
        self.sheet = self.wb.active
        log_info('Loaded excel file "%s"' % self.config['excel_file'])
        try:
            self.server_config = json.load(self.config['config'])
            if not 'mail_user' in self.server_config:
                raise ValueError()
            log_debug('Parsed config file "%s".' % self.config['config'].name)
        except ValueError:
            log_error('Failed to parse config "%s".' % self.config['config'].name)
            return False

        connections = list()
        for connection in self.server_config['mail_user']:
            sender = Mail_sender(connection, self._persist_config, nosend=self.config['nosend'])
            # TODO: should we try to connect with every user once here ?
            log_info('Loaded data for connection %s@%s:%i' % (sender.username, sender.host, sender.port))
            connections.append(sender)
        self.server_connections = connections
        return True

    def _persist_config(self):
        self.config['config'].seek(0)
        json.dump(self.server_config, self.config['config'], indent=True, sort_keys=True)
        self.config['config'].truncate()
        self.config['config'].flush() # Do we need this here ?

    def _find_free_server(self):
        a = sorted(((x.next_send, x) for x in self.server_connections))
        return a[0]

    def close(self):
        self.wb.save(self.config['excel_file'])

    def run(self):
        row_select = (self.config['colmail'], self.config['colsubject'], self.config['colbody'], self.config['colsend'])
        for row in excel_data_iterator(self.wb, self.config['sheetindex'], row_select):
            row = list(row)
            if 'staticsubject' in self.config:
                row[2] = self.config['staticsubject']
            if row[4] and row[4] >= 1:
                log_debug('Skip row %i, because it was already send.' % row[0])
                continue

            next_send, connection = self._find_free_server()
            if now() < next_send:
                _next = next_send - now()
                log_debug('Next mail send in %i seconds' % _next)
                sleep(_next)

            failed = False
            if not row[1] or not row[2] or not row[3]:
                log_error('Invalid data in row %i. Skipping row.' % (row[0] + 1))
                failed = True
            else:
                try:
                    status = connection.send_mail(row[1], row[2], row[3], retries=3, sleep_time=5) 
                except smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused as e:
                    log_error('Recipients refused (%s) for connection %s@%s:%i' % (row[1], connection.username, connection.host, connection.port))
                    failed = True
            if failed:
                self.sheet.cell(row=row[0] + 1, column=self.config['colsend'] + 1).value = 2
                self.wb.save(self.config['excel_file'])
                continue

            if status:
                self.sheet.cell(row=row[0] + 1, column=self.config['colsend'] + 1).value = 1
                self.wb.save(self.config['excel_file'])
            else:
                # We do NOT set the error or done flag when there is an critical error
                # as it is probably some network or configuration error- 
                log_error('Critical error. Going down.')
                return False


def test_mail(config):
    server_config = json.load(config['config'])
    for connection in server_config['mail_user']:
        log_info('Try to connect to %s@%s:%i ...' % (connection['username'], connection['host'], connection['port']))
        sender = Mail_sender(connection, None)
        try:
            sender.connect_to_server()
            log_info('Connection valid.')
            sender.close()
        except smtplib.SMTPHeloError:
            log_error('The server didn\'t reply properly to the HELO greeting.')
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            log_error('The server didn\'t accept the username/password combination.')
        except smtplib.SMTPException:
            log_error('No suitable authentication method was found.')
        except socket.error as e:
            log_error('Network error: %s' % e)

def test_spreadsheet_file(config, cleancomments):
    from tempfile import mkstemp
    error = False
    log_info('Trying to load spreadsheet file "%s" ...' % config['excel_file'])
    try:
        book = load_workbook(config['excel_file'], use_iterators=False, keep_vba=True)
    except InvalidFileException:
        log_error('Invalid file. Can\'t open')
        return True

    if cleancomments:
        log_info('Cleaning comments for temporary file')
        for i in xrange(len(book.get_sheet_names())):
            book.active = i
            for row in book.active.rows:
                for cell in row: cell.comment = None
    suffix = '.' + config['excel_file'].split('.')[-1]
    book.active = config['sheetindex']
    # Sometimes max_row isn't correct, so we shouldn't rely on it. TODO: it would be great if we could
    log_info('Loading succesfully. %i rows found.' % book.active.max_row)

    # https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/536/cant-save-and-reopen-xlsx-file-with
    log_debug('Checking for comment bug ...')
    tmp_file, tmp_name = mkstemp(suffix=suffix)
    os.close(tmp_file)
    book.save(tmp_name)
    fd = open(tmp_name, 'rb')
    try:
        book = load_workbook(filename=fd, use_iterators=False, keep_vba=True)
        book.active = config['sheetindex']
        log_info('Comment bug not detected. Rows %i' % book.active.max_row)
    except TypeError as e:
        log_error('Failed reloading file. Try again with added --cleancomments parameter.')
        error = True
    fd.close()
    os.remove(tmp_name)
    return error 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # TODO: CSV ? The default lib has unicode problems
    import sys
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sends emails with data supplied by excel files.')
    parser.add_argument('--config', '-c', required=True, type=argparse.FileType('r+b'), default='./config.json', help='Choose the configuration file.')
    parser.add_argument('--loglvl', '-l', help='Set the log level.', default='INFO', choices=('DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARN', 'ERROR'))
    parser.add_argument('--logfile', '-f', type=argparse.FileType('w'), help='Also write log to file.')
    parser.add_argument('--colmail', '-m', type=int, default=0, help='The column containing the email address.')
    parser.add_argument('--colsubject', '-s', type=int, default=1, help='The column containing the email subjects.')
    parser.add_argument('--colbody', '-b', type=int, default=2, help='The column containing the email message.')
    parser.add_argument('--colsend', '-o', type=int, default=3, help='The column used to mark if the mail was send.')
    parser.add_argument('--staticsubject', '-x', help='Can be used to use a static subject.')
    parser.add_argument('--sheetindex', '-i', type=int, default=0, help='The sheet to use.')
    parser.add_argument('--cleancomments', action='store_true', help='Remove comments from file. Openpyxl has/hadd a bug leading to corrupt files otherwise.')
    parser.add_argument('excel_file', type=argparse.FileType('r+b'), help='The excel file to get data from.')
    parser.add_argument('--test', action='store_true', help='Only test all mail accounts and the spreadsheet file. Then exit.')       
    parser.add_argument('--nosend', action='store_true', help='Do NOT send the mails. Used for testing.')       
    parser.add_argument('--notest', action='store_true', help='Do NOT test for comment bug on startup.')       
    params = vars(parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:]))

    # Get filename of the excel file (used to check perms)
    file_name = params['excel_file'].name
    params['excel_file'].close()
    params['excel_file'] = file_name

    # Set up logging
    if params['loglvl'] == 'DEBUG':
        log_lvl = logging.DEBUG 
    elif params['loglvl'] == 'INFO':
        log_lvl = logging.INFO 
    elif params['loglvl'] == 'WARN':
        log_lvl = logging.WARN 
    elif params['loglvl'] == 'ERROR':
        log_lvl = logging.ERROR
    if 'logfile' in params:
        logging.basicConfig(filename=params['logfile'], format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d %I:%M %p', level=log_lvl)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=log_lvl, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d %I:%M %p')

    if params['test']:
        test_mail(params)
        test_spreadsheet_file(params, params['cleancomments'])
        exit()

    if not params['notest']:
        log_info('Testing file integrity and comment bug...')
        if test_spreadsheet_file(params, params['cleancomments']):
            exit()

    sender = Excel_Mail_Sender(params)
    if sender.init():
        try:
            sender.run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sender.close()
```

*I hope the code isn't to large and in scope of this site. It is my first time posting on codereview.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general long code is ok here, though it's easier for reviewers if there's a compact piece of code to review. As it is, I'll give some notes I thought of from reading through your code.

You double up on some code in `_update_quotas`

```
if mail_send:
    self.next_send = curtime + ceil(self.config['timeframe'] / self.config['allowed_requests'])
else:
    self.next_send = curtime
```

In either case you will need `self.next_send = curtime`, so why not initialise that first and then add the extra value `if mail_send`.

```
self.next_send = curtime
if mail_send:
    self.next_send += ceil(self.config['timeframe'] / self.config['allowed_requests'])
```

If you intend for it to be

```
    self.next_send = (curtime + ceil(self.config['timeframe']) / self.config['allowed_requests'])
```

then I don't believe that's how your code interprets. It's definitely not how the order of operations on mine works:

```
>>> 10 + 10 / 10
11
>>> (10 + 10) / 10
2
```

You're using the old string formatting with `%`, you should use `str.format` instead as it's easier. It coerces data to strings and offers syntax for additional formatting so it's good to be used to. It's not a big change in your case.

```
log_debug('Can send 1 mail every {} second for {}@{}:{}. {} requests remaining in frame.'.format(mail_delay, self.username, self.host, self.port, self.config['remaining_requests']))
```

Every `{}` substitutes in one the values passed to it. You'll notice that I don't need to indicate datatype any more.

The other note about this line is that it's far too long! You should try to keep to 79 characters per line as the style guide dictates. One way of doing that is with implicit string concatenation. If you have multiple string literals in sequence with nothing between them, they'll be concatenated:

```
>>> "concat" "enation"
'concatenation'
>>> ("concat"
     "enation")
'concatenation'
```

As you can see this works over multiple lines, and even works with `str.format`:

```
>>> ("{}"
 "concat"
 "enation".format("This is "))
'This is concatenation'
```

So you could split the line up like this:

```
log_debug('Can send 1 mail every {} second for {}@{}:{}.'
          '{} requests remaining in frame.'
          .format(mail_delay, self.username, self.host, self.port,
                  self.config['remaining_requests']))
```

Note that I'm matching the indentation to where the brackets open, to make it clear where each parentheses open.

Bare excepts are always bad, and they're worse when you're trying to close a connection. What if the user hits a keyboard interrupt? You're just going to let that pass without safely closing anything? Instead, figure out what exceptions could occur and only catch those to handle or log, you did a good job with the exceptions in `send_mail`, do similar here. At the very least you should log the exception somehow so you'll be able to refer back and see what you've been letting pass.

Instead of escaping quotes with backslash, you can just wrap the text in double quotes when you need single quotes and vice versa

```
log_error("The server didn't accept the username/password combination.")
```

Instead of using a chain of string comparisons, you can use a dictionary to set your log levels:

```
LOG_LEVELS = {
                'DEBUG': logging.DEBUG,
                'INFO': logging.INFO,
                'WARN': logging.WARN,
                'ERROR': logging.ERROR,
             }

log_lvl = LOG_LEVELS[params['loglvl']]
```

Comment: *Pressed enter to fast*. Thanks for the answers.  I will follow the styling guidelines you suggested. Esp. using a dict for the log level is a good advise. The calculation of *next_send* is correct. It should return the current time plus the calculated time delta.  Is there any reason in my case to use the new format string syntax in py2.7 ? I am pretty used to the old style and almost never need any more formatting in there.  About the bare except:I will change this. Also you reminded me that i do NOT close the connection on key interrupt (only closing the xlsx file in that case). THX again.

Comment: Glad to help! In your case, format just means you don't need to care about the data type. But it's the standard so it's good to match how other code will look.